# magento 2 which event used for after order success and product save

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 which event used for after order success and product saved in backend. I have created catalog_product_save_after event once saved product inserted data to my custom table. But the problem is once an order is placed from frontend this event is not triggered.so I need the event for after order success product save the event

Comment: you have to use this event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` and after that, you have to load the ordered item and get the product id from that and update it to the related product table and custom table. Hope this one helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below events

> checkout_submit_all_after
>
> catalog_product_save_after

After order place sucess - use this `"checkout_submit_all_after"` in

> app/code/Your/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

After product save after -  use this `"catalog_product_save_after"` in

> app/code/Your/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

you can use both event on global level too. use both events on below path

> app/code/Your/Module/etc/events.xml

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this event order order success.

> checkout_submit_all_after

Comment: where i have add events.xml for this event  etc/frontend/events.xml or etc/adminhtml/events.xml  already added this event under  etc/frontend/events.xml not working

Comment: you need to put into the "etc"